# Why does django_tables2 render the same table twice?

Tags: django, django-tables2

I am using django_tables2 to create some tables. My app is called 'director' and I have a base template and then a child template that inherits from it. The code mostly works as expected--the child template is correctly inheriting the divss and stuff from the parent and the styling is right, but then the child also outputs the same table a second time, this time without the styling from the parent. I can't figure out for the life of me why the second table is getting generated.

Here is the base template.

```
#director_table.html
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4 mt-4">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-header">List</div>
            <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle"></h6>

                {% block table_stuff %}

                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And here's the child.

```
{% extends 'director/director_table.html' %}
    {% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
    {% block content %} 
    {{ block.super }}

        {% block table_stuff %}
            {% render_table table %}
        {% endblock %}

    {% endblock %}
```

[image]

***edit***

If I comment out the {% render_table table %} line, then I get 0 tables, not 2.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. The solution was to divide the css/bootstrap stuff into further blocks.

the parent template:

```
{% block content %}
    {% block top %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4 mt-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="card-header">List</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle"></h6>
    {% endblock %}
                    {% block table_stuff %}

                    {% endblock %}
    {% block bottom %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

and the child:

```
{% extends 'director/director_table.html' %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% block content %}
    {% block top %}
    {{ block.super }}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block table_stuff %}
        {% render_table table %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block bottom %}
    {{block.super}}
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

This gives the expected result.
[image]